# Suma de unica fila de matrices

Tags: c

tengo una matriz 3x10 pero quiero sumar una unica fila de esa matriz porque quiero sacar un promedio de los valores de cada fila individualmente. Asi tengo estructurado el codigo,el problema que tengo es que en la fila 0 suma 30 valores y yo solo quiero que sume los de su fila unicamente que son 10.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
        float A[3][10];
        int sumA,sumA2,sumA3;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
                A[i][j]=0;
    }
}

       for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("\n\t Sucursal %d de la ciudad A",i+1);
          for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf("\nIngrese el sueldo N.%d ",j+1);
        scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
        sumA=sumA+A[0][j];
        sumA2=sumA2+A[1][j];        
        sumA3=sumA3+A[2][j];
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No está sumando los 30 campos, sino que está sumando los 10 campos de las filas 3 veces, como los otros comienzan con 0 no ves mucho problema en ellos.

Saca las sumas de los `for` que usas como inputs y ponlo en un `for` adicional:

```c
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("\n\t Sucursal %d de la ciudad A",i+1);
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        printf("\nIngrese el sueldo N.%d ",j+1);
        scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    sumA=sumA+A[0][j];
    sumA2=sumA2+A[1][j];
    sumA3=sumA3+A[2][j];
}
```